# Sign CSR with LetsEncrypt Wild card cert

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have successfully requested a wildcard cert for a domain I own.
Now I want to use a subdomain CNAME `(manager.<MY_DOMAIN>.com)` to be used on a different machine.

I've created a CSR from that machine and now I guess I need to sign this CSR somehow from my machine, where the wildcard cert is located.

However I don't know how.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Server and my letsencrypt cert is under **/etc/letsencrypt/**

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The signing is done by the CA (in this case, Let's Encrypt).  You must submit the CSR to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a wildcard cert for *.example.com then you do not need another cert for subdomain.example.com. Just use the certificate and key files for *.example.com.

It is still valid to have a separate cert for specific subdomains though, so if you do not wish to use the wildcard *.example.com certificate files just follow the same process to get a new cert for subdomain.example.com specifically.